# RoboGuice: inject class by hand in normal class

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, roboguice

I have some interfaces and some concreted classes implement those interfaces. I have config in `AbstractModule` class.

But my problem is: `@Inject` just works inside a RoboGuice class such as `RoboFragment`, `RoboActivity` ...

For example:

```
public class Fragment extends RoboFragment {

  @Inject
  ICustomClass helper; // work. helper will be initialized and call successfully. 

}

public class JavaNormalClass {
  @Inject
  ICustomClass helper;  // doesn't work. NullPointerException
}
```

So, I think `RoboGuice` doesn't inject custom class when it's inside normal class so that I should call it by hand. (I guess !!!) So, how to fix my problem ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simple solution work for me.

You put this line of code before you call any `@Inject` member. Best way maybe in constructor of normal class or `onCreate` of activity ...

```
public class CustomClass {

   @Inject
   IDBDAL dbDAL;

   // can be application context or activity context
   private Context mContext;

   public CustomClass() {
      // you can get context variable somewhere else 
      mContext = MyApplication.getAppContext(); 
      RoboGuice.getInjector(mContext).injectMembersWithoutViews(this);
      // from now. you can use dbDAL object
      dbDAL.doSomething(); // work like charm :)
   }
}
```

I think this solution is generic, and can apply to multiple situations. Hope this help :)